# SVN deleting a "file.sln" and "file.suo"

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've accidently imported a visual studio project directly in the main folder instead of putting it in the folder inside the main folder. (i wonder if that's clear ?)

I've been able to delete everything exept the .suo and .sln, i don't want to delete the whole main file cause there is other project in there. Maybe a picture is worth a thousand words :

[image]

No error message, nothing happens when i push delete... nothing, any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tortoise, i rigth clicked on my project and used repo-browser, and from there i was able to delete everything. Strange behaviour though.

Answer (score 2):

VisualSVN Server Manager console provides a command to delete files beginning with version 3.5.0.

Alternatively you can use Subversion client to delete files or folders. For example, run the following command line:

`svn rm https://svn.example.com/svn/Production/MandatMobile.sln -m "Removed a file."`

Comment: VisualSVN Server Manager console provides a command to delete files beginning with [version 3.5.0](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.5.0): *VisualSVN Server Manager now provides a command to delete a file from repository.*